# Efficient List Ordering

Tags: c#, performance, linq, list

I am currently testing whats the best algorithm to order a list by a Key Value.

I have a very simple object (following code snippets are from C#)

```
class BasicObject
{
int Key;
}
```

The Key gets randomly set when constructing the Object.

So I have a List of `BasicObject` objects which needs to be ordered by the Key Value in the end.

```
List<BasicObject> basicList = new List<BasicObject>();
for (int i = 0; i < someAmount; i++)
{
basicList.Add(new BasicObject());
}
```

My idea was, to make a new list called `orderedList` or so, and loop through it every time, for every `BasicObject`, and check whether its Key is higher than the current Value or lower.
Something like that:

```
List<BasicObject> orderedList = new List<BasicObject>();
bool objectWasInserted = false;
orderedList.Add(basicList[0]); // Inserting 1 Object as reference for the upcoming loop

for (int i = 1; i < someAmount; i++)
{
objectWasInserted = false;

for (int c = 0; c < orderedList.Count; c++)
{

if (basicList[i].Key > orderedList[c].Key) // The Key of the current object is higher than the key of the current object of the ordered List
{
orderedList.Insert(c, basicList[i]);
objectWasInserted = true;
break;
}

}

if (!objectWasInserted)
{
orderedList.Add(basicList[i]);
}
}
```

Even though this works, it is way too slow.
Tested with 50000 Objects it already takes 8 seconds.

The LINQ Method `OrderBy` is much faster.

```
orderedList = basicList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Key).ToList();
```

Takes only 7 milli Seconds for 50000 Objects!

However, this is a helper method, I want to get away from it and rather use my own algorithm to order a list of objects by a key.

I also tried a LinkedList instead of a normal List. which is a little bit faster, but still far away from the LINQ method.

So is there a way, to speed up the ordering of Objects a little? :)

Thanks for your help, in advance!!

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong with Linq *'However this is a helper method, I want to get away from it and rather use my own algorithm to order a list of objects by a key.'*?

Comment: Yes. By changing the programming language at a later point, I am maybe not able to use Linqs methods. So I am looking forward to have my own classes for everything, as less dependent from library's as it gets

Comment: If you will change programming language, then there could not be `List<T>` class, or classes at all. Consider not to use collections and classes then

Comment: That is, why I am asking. Maybe it is more efficient, using an array or some kind of connection between the BasicObjects...

Comment: It's more efficient to use power of language and framework you are using now. Also I believe all high-level languages have built-in functionality for sorting collections

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Linq (which looks very strange to me), you can use [`List<T>.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
basicList.Sort((o1,o2) => o1.Key.CompareTo(o2.Key));
```

NOTE: This method will modify original list instead of creating new one.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you want to use your own algorithm, it won't be as efficient and fast as the algorithm implemented in the LINQ [`OrderByDescending()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534855%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. We don't know which sort algorithm is used in LINQ, but we know it's already optimized, implemented to be efficient and to use the power of framework, otherwise it wouldn't take 7 ms to sort 50000 objects.

Take a look at [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm), to consider the different sorting algorithms.

If you'll change programming language, you'll have to use the features of that programming language. It doesn't make sense to me to start implementing a sorting algorithm when there's already one, optimized for the language you're currently using, like C#, if you have to change the programming language. If you already know which language you'll use, consider then the tools that language can offer to solve your problems.